# ASP Gridview - Pager Settings Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my ASP.NET page, I'm using a GridView to view data and set paging mode = "NextPreviousFirstLast" but only show Next and Last.

Answer (score 0):

The pager (assuming you have it working) does not show anything if you don't have enough data to page.

However, on first page load, it only shows next, and last like this:

[image]

so above shows next ">"   and ">>" for last

but, if I just hit next, THEN the display will show first, Previous, next, and last like this:

[image]

So, on start - you not see the "previous" until such time you move forward.

You can also insert a pager template - and that would in theory allow you custom buttons.